# Form data validation not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I would like to validate names.

Ex: if I enter vinod98 r vinod_ it should give me an error message.
I want to move to start.js page after enter the name and clicked on participate. Can someone help me to do this

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Aptitude Competition Online</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function validate()
         {  
         var nam = document.forms[0].name.value; 
         var reg = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
         if(nam == "") 
           { 
            alert("Name should be filled out"); 
            document.getElementById("name").focus();
             return false;
           } 
         else if (!reg.match(nam))
           { 
              alert("Name contains only letters");
              document.forms[0].name.focus();
              return false; 
           }
         else {  
            return true; 
              } 
          }
      </script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header1">
         <font id="font1">Aptitude Quiz</font>
      </div>
      <div id="bgr">
         <div id="emal">
            <font style="position:absolute;top:16px;left:100px;font-size:20px;">Welcome to Aptitude Quiz</font><br><br><br>
            <form name="form">
               Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
               <input name="Participate" type="button" value="Participate" onClick="validate()">
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
         Contact Us : gmail@name.com 
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share a jsfiddle.

Comment: what does jsfiddle mean ?

Comment: You should use jQuery and external CSS styling.

Comment: I have external stylesheet

Comment: I see now have an external style sheet.
 You could use it instead of having:
<font style="position:absolute;top:16px;left:100px;font-size:20px>

Also, I changed start.jsp to start.js but maybe you did mean start.jsp

Comment: JSfiddle is a code sharing/editing site

http://jsfiddle.net/

Upload your code to it and share the link so people who view your question can look at your code and try to help.

Comment: i removed <font style="position:absolute;top:16px;left:100px;font-size:20px>. Even though i removed it it isn't working.

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle :      https://jsfiddle.net/xj7omho5/

Answer (score 0):

I rectified the error. Just remove reg in the if statement and then use test method. It works fine